# WCF: Routing service and "Unable to automatically debug 'service name'. The remote procedure could not be debugged

Tags: wcf, iis-7

Recently we added the new WCF Routing Service to our project.  While debugging a test client calling to one of our test services, we are getting an error message with the following message:

```
    Unable to automatically debug 'Service Name'.  The remote procedure could 
    not be debugged. This usually indicates that debugging has not been enabled 
    on the server.  See help for more information.
```

The strange thing is that the debugger is still able to connect to the indicated service name.  If I point my client to the service directly, the error dialog does not appear.  I've checked the web configs on all services, debugging is enabled.  There is also no security model being specified as I've seen on other posts.

The service is being hosted in IIS on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1.  Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate with SP1.

Comment: Experienced the same "fake" problem using VS2010SP1 and IIS Express on a Seven x64 box!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I solved this issue by going to

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
```

then running

```
vsdiag_regwcf.exe -i
```

What this does:

```
-i     Install Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink to enable
       Visual Studio debugger and profiler support for Windows Communication
       Foundation services.
```

**Remark:** I'm running an x64 version of Win7, and though 99% of Visual Studio is located in **C:\Program Files (x86)\**, this tool is in **C:\Program Files\**

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.  I don't know that it is a simple environment configuration issue since every machine I've worked with exhibits the same behavior.  I'll keep my fingers crossed.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! On Win7 x64 w/ VS2K8 and the VS development server. Please note though, it only takes effect until you have restarted VS and/or the VS development server.

Comment: Thanks!  This fixed my issue.  I had to launch a Developer Command Prompt for VS 2015, as Administrator.  Fixed my issue immediately without restarting.

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\vsdiag_regwcf.exe" for me!  And "Thanks!"